# Where are Django User model fields saved?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sorry, if this is a very basic question, but I was wondering where Django User model field values like `is_active` are saved as I don't see them in the database.

I am using a custom User model, but they must still be saved somewhere... :)

models.py

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        self.username = username
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    ...

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    is_active = False

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    ...
```

Tables in database:

```
 Schema |          Name          | Type  |   Owner    
--------+------------------------+-------+------------
 public | auth_group             | table | xxx
 public | auth_group_permissions | table | xxx
 public | auth_permission        | table | xxx
 public | django_admin_log       | table | xxx
 public | django_content_type    | table | xxx
 public | django_migrations      | table | xxx
 public | django_session         | table | xxx
 public | drillapp_myuser        | table | xxx
 public | drillapp_question      | table | xxx
 public | drillapp_story         | table | xxx
(10 rows)
```

This is how the user table looks. No `is_active` column.

```
drill=# select * from drillapp_myuser;
 id |               password                | last_login |        email         
----+---------------------------------------+------------+----------------------
 45 | pbkdf2_sha256$36000$GNzjZ...edPewC28= |            | xxx0@xxx.com
(1 row)
```

In the shell I can access the `is_active` field, which I don't see in the database:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> u = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=45)
>>> u.is_active
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case `is_active` is the python class `property` that does not saved in the database, if you want to save and manipulate it you should use [`models.BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField)